# Regex Allow Alpha Numeric With Max Character Till 12 Digits

Tags: regex

I had tried regex `^[0-9\b]` for accept only numeric character, but my objective is want to allow the number entered up to 12 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be simplified to: `^\d{0,12}$`

You used word boundary `\b` wrong, putting it in character class, because it is matched optionally. To make it mandatory, you need to place it after whole pattern, as I did with `$` which matches end of a string.

Further explanation:

`^` matches beginnning of a string

`\d` matches digit, equivlant to `[0-9]`

`{0, 12}` - limits matching preceeding pattern to match between 0 and 12 times.

Comment: Thanks @Michal Turczyn Im really appreciated with your help :D